# committing stored procedures into TFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created and executed stored procedures in `sql server manager`. In my visual studios server explorer i noticed the stored procedures are there properly. Not sure what i have to do or where to go to find these stored procedure to commit into `TFS`.

**QUESTION**

What do i need to do to have the created stored procedures committed into `TFS`?

- Do i have to run or create the stored procedure in visual studios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedures need to be added to a project that is under source control with TFS.

Comment: Stored Procedures... please tell me your stored procedures are for data manipulation and not for business logic! Also, no special characters in your SQL. </rant>